Detect if figure is at top of page
I am looking for a way to detect if a figure is placed at the top of a page, regardless of wether it as 't' assigned as position option. I tried using \pagegoal and \pagetotal, but that does not work. Consider this example:
\documentclass[twoside]{scrbook}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\lipsum
\begin{figure}[t!]%
\the\pagegoal, \the\pagetotal%
\end{figure}
\lipsum
\clearpage
\lipsum
\begin{figure}[t!]%
\caption{\the\pagegoal, \the\pagetotal}%
\end{figure}
\lipsum


\end{document}

The printed text reads 595.80026pt, 53.92918pt and I don't think it is possible to detect from this that it is at the top of the page. For the second figure, the caption reads 595.80026pt, 53.92918pt, which is also not helpful.
How can I detect if a figure is placed at the top of the page, before any text on the page, except page number, header etc.?

@cfr pagegoal is meaningless in a figure it reflects where the box was typeset not where the figure is finally placed you need pdfsavepos

You can store y-coordinate (or ypos) of what you would consider to be "the top of the page" and then compare other stored positions against that.
The code below uses \saveypos{<label>} to store the ypos in that <label> (technically a value denoting the small points - sp - from the bottom of the page).
The figure environment is "intercepted" to extract the \caption[.]{..} and then place it at the top or the bottom of the figure depending on final placement of the figure.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum,showframe}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_set_eq:NN \oldfigure \figure
\cs_set_eq:NN \endoldfigure \endfigure
\tl_new:N \l_env_body_text_tl
\seq_new:N \l_caption_seq

% To allow for passing a token list (tl) to the second argument of \regex_match
% This supplies the variant \regex_match:nVTF
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \regex_match:nnTF {nV}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \regex_extract_once:nnN {nVN}
\RenewDocumentEnvironment{figure}{ O{htbp} +b }{}{
  \tl_set:Nn \l_env_body_text_tl { #2 } % Store figure environment body in tl
  \seq_clear:N \l_caption_seq % Clear caption sequence
  
  % Retrieve \caption[.]{..} from body/tl
  \regex_extract_once:nVN
    { \c{caption} \[? .* \]? \{ .* \} } % <search>: \caption[.]{..}
    { \l_env_body_text_tl } % <text>
    \l_caption_seq % <stored result>
  % Remove \caption[.]{..} in body/tl
  \regex_replace_once:nnN
    { \c{caption} \[? .* \]? \{ .* \} } % <search>: \caption[ ]{  }
    { } % <replacement>
    \l_env_body_text_tl % <text>
  
  % Set figure
  \begin{oldfigure}[#1]
    \saveypos{top-figure-\thefigure}% Record y coordinate
    % Compare first ypos with current figure ypos
    \int_compare:nNnTF { \RefProperty[-1]{first}{ypos} } = { \RefProperty[-2]{top-figure-\thefigure}{ypos} }
      { % <true>
        \vspace*{-\abovecaptionskip} % Remove typical \abovecaptionskip above caption
        \seq_item:Nn \l_caption_seq { 1 } % Set \caption
        \vspace{\abovecaptionskip} % Insert \abovecaptionskip below caption
        \tl_use:N \l_env_body_text_tl % Set figure
      }
      { % <false>
        \tl_use:N \l_env_body_text_tl % Set figure
        \seq_item:Nn \l_caption_seq { 1 } % Set \caption
      }
  \end{oldfigure}
}

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \property_record:nn {xn}
\NewDocumentCommand{\saveypos}{ m }{%
  \tex_savepos:D
  \property_record:xn {#1} {ypos}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\AddToHook{env/document/begin}{\saveypos{first}}% Store what is considered "the top of the page"

\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\lipsum[1]

% This figure is not at the top
\begin{figure}[htb]
  \centering This is a figure.
  \caption{Abc}
\end{figure}

\clearpage

% This figure is at the top
\begin{figure}[htb]
  \centering This is another figure.
  \caption[def]{Def}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}

\RefProperty[<default>]{<label>}{<property>} returns the <property> of the <label>, and <default> if it doesn't exist (yet). Note that you need at least two compilations with every change of the labels' ypos.

This may be a crude example, and require some additional finessing based on your use case. However, it shows a proof of concept.

The example doesnt work for me. The figure is placed at the top, but is not detected as such.

@HerpDerpington: Can you provide more context? Supply an example where my code fails.

It seems I copied something wrong because I can no longer reproduce it

But I have a question: Is there a way to redefine the figure environment or add a hook or similar, to automatically collect the y positions?

@HerpDerpington: Yes, you can do that. What do you want to do in instances with a figure at the top of the page? Can you provide more context?

The caption should be placed above the figure in those cases.

@HerpDerpington: Try this code. It automates the process of switching out the \caption from below/above the figure contents, depending on whether the image appears at the top of the page or not.
